# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: - Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to Inserat something from Input into my Database. But getting the Error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: kundename

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('datenbank.db')
print ("Opened database successfully")

kundenname= input("Kundename: ")
auftragstyp= input("Auftragstyp: ")
auftragsurl= input("Auftragsurl: ")
anzahl= input("Anzahl der Bewertungen: ")

conn.execute("INSERT INTO kundenname VALUES (kundename,auftragstyp,auftragsurl,anzahl)", (kundenname, auftragstyp,         auftragsurl,  anzahl))

conn.commit()
print ("Records created successfully")
conn.close()
```

**But if I make like:**

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('datenbank.db')

print ("Opened database successfully")

conn = conn.execute("SELECT ID, kundename from kundenname")
for row in conn:
print ("ID = ", row[0])
print ("kundename = ", row[1])
print ("Operation done successfully")
conn.close()
```

then it works and Shows me the Datas in the Base. But why insert saying the colum dosent excist?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Typo in `kundenname`?

Comment: No, I wrote it like this in DB to ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with this line:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO kundenname VALUES 
(kundename,auftragstyp,auftragsurl,anzahl)", (kundenname, auftragstyp,         
auftragsurl,  anzahl))
```

This is not the way to insert, try this:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO kundenname 
('kundename','auftragstyp','auftragsurl','anzahl') VALUES (" + 
str(kundename) +"," + str(auftragstyp) + "," +  str(auftragsurl) + "," 
+ str(anzahl)+")"
```

Comment: It says then: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Michi , he looking as colum what I put into the Input.

Comment: Only works if I use numbers as Input.. if I add letters then it Comes the error that the colum dosent excist emm

Comment: That's because SQL requires single quotes around each string value, but not for numeric values. So it all depends on your database field types as to how you insert the data. So if auftragsurl is a text field, the VALUE should be like ...`",'" + str(auftragsurl) + '","...` and an integer insertion looks like ...`, anzahl,`... assuming anzahl is an integer.

Comment: I have as kundename ...+ str(kundename) +... and in database kundename is Text. Still he dont add it in the database, he search the Input as a colum and but adding a number it works.. but why if it is TEXT :)

Comment: I did not understand if it helped you or not...can you please post the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is complaining about your using unquoted strings. It's interpreting them as variable names in your insert statement. Try this:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO kundenname ('kundename','auftragstyp','auftragsurl','anzahl') VALUES (kundenname, auftragstyp,  auftragsurl,  anzahl)")
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting the error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Comment: The problem was the comma before the word VALUE. I removed it from the answer.

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: kundenname

Comment: And if I Change it into:
+ str(kundenname) + , it Comes:
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Hans